# Multi-threaded Named Pipe Server

Tags: c#, .net, named-pipes

I'm trying to create a Multi-Threaded Named Pipe Server which can handle multiple requests in parallel.  See below for my code.

The behaviour is not as expected.  If new requests come in while the current one is busy it throws "access to the path is denied" error until the current executing thread is released.

Any idea what could be the problem ?

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace API.PipeServer
{
    public class Server
    {
        private bool running;
        private Thread runningThread;
        private EventWaitHandle terminateHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
        public string PipeName { get; set; }

        private void ServerLoop()
        {
            while (running)
            {
                ProcessNextClient();
            }

            terminateHandle.Set();
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            running = true;
            runningThread = new Thread(ServerLoop);
            runningThread.Start();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            running = false;
            terminateHandle.WaitOne();
        }

        public virtual string ProcessRequest(string message)
        {
            return "";
        }

        public void ProcessClientThread(object o)
        {
            using (NamedPipeServerStream pipeStream = (NamedPipeServerStream)o)
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeStream);

                //Receive instruction message
                string instructionJson = sr.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}: --- Receiving Instruction ---");
                Console.WriteLine(instructionJson);

                //Getting instruction message
                var instruction = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InstructionHandler.Instruction>(instructionJson);

                //Get data
                var json = API.API.GetAPIJson(instruction);

                //Send data back to Python client
                try
                {
                    pipeStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
                    pipeStream.WaitForPipeDrain();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}: --- Closing Stream ---");

                pipeStream.Close();
                pipeStream.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public void ProcessNextClient()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}: Creating server");
                PipeSecurity pipeSecurity = new PipeSecurity();
                pipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow));

                var pipeStream = NamedPipeServerStreamAcl.Create("test_api", PipeDirection.InOut, 254, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.None, 1024, 1024, pipeSecurity);

                pipeStream.WaitForConnection();

                //Spawn a new thread for each request and continue waiting
                Thread t = new Thread(ProcessClientThread);
                t.Start(pipeStream);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}: Error - {e.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is a typical output:

[image]

Comment: Try to instantiate your "pipeStream" with the word "using", instead of assign it to "var"...it could be a memory issue. Also, try to give diferent names to "pipeStream"..

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues cannot add using as the object is used by the  thread.  Alos cannot give the pipe a different name.  Pipe supports multiple connections.

Comment: I understand it. I was pointing to the "pipeStream " on "ProcessNextClient" void.

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues ok thanks I tried it but no change in behaviour.

Comment: It is not obvious at all from the code or the question why you liked 254

Comment: @HansPassant I've read that 254 is the maximum amount of pipes that can be opened.  It can be 10 as well.  Don't think I will use more than 10 if it runs in parallel

Comment: Underneath every undebuggable problem there's at least one bad assumption.  Use SemaphoreSlim to ensure the limit can never be exceeded.